# Backup of multiple server with snapshot

Tags: backup, rsnapshot

I have three server that I need to be able to pull backups from using rnsapshot and save backups to a single backup server. How would I do it? So far all the guides I have read has one server in mind.

I am also trying to find out whats the best way to backup an ubuntu server? I would like to backup as much information as possible so that during a disaster I should be able to restore to my working state with minimum effort using rsnapshot.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to just add the 3 servers into your rnspahsot.conf file. What I would do is this as an example:

```
# Server 1 backup
backup  user1@server1:/etc/ server1/

# Server 2 backup
backup  user2@server2:/etc/ server2/

# Server 3 backup
backup  user3@server3:/etc/ server3/
```

The above will backup the /etc directories on all 3 servers to your local rsnapshot backup server in their respective directories e.g. server1/ server2 and so forth. You can of course add many other directories such as /home /var/www and so on.

To answer your other question that depends on what you really need to achieve in regards to a disaster recovery. rsnapshot is really only backing up your directories and files on the server. I personally use it for data and configuration files at a point in time and then use other tools for major disasters such as VM backup imaging tools. I assume you are using virtual machines?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. No I am not using virtual machine. Will it be possible to backup all the contents of the disk using rsnapshot. Basically I am looking for a solution which silently backups up a system in the background and should be able to restore to a working server with minimal effort.